# Rewriteing a GET request with mod rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can anyone explain me how to rewrite get request in a search form.

This is the code of my form

```
<form action="searchpage.php" method="get ">
        <input type="text" name="search"  placeholder="Search" required>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

and this is the line i use in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule searchpage-search-(.*)\.html$ searchpage.php?search=$1 [L]
```

But this doesn't seems to work. if anyone can help me out with this, it will be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to externally redirect users when they do a search request? That seems counterproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form does a request to `/searchpage.php?search=term`, so you'll first need an external redirect to redirect the user from that url to your custom url. Then you need an internal rewrite to properly interpret that. To do an external redirect for every search request your users do seems however counter-productive to me.

```
#The external redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /searchpage\.php\?search=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^searchpage\.php$ /searchpage-search-%2.html? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule searchpage-search-(.*)\.html$ searchpage.php?search=$1 [L]
```

Comment: it works but still its showing `?search=term` at the end of the url after `.html` extension

Comment: @zack Made a minor change in the first rule. Forgot to append a trailing `?` to clear the current query string.